# Footer conflicts

Tags: footnotes

I am a beginner! I am trying to add a footnote on a specific page using the following command:

```
\section [title]{Section Title xxx\footnote{footnote here}}
```

which works well and adds the `footnote here` as the footnote.

The problem is as soon as I add the footnote, the header on the next pages does not show up correctly anymore. Instead of the section title (here `Section Title xxx`) to appear as the left header, **only** the word "title" appears on all the next pages.

I use the following commands to place headers:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1] {\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}] {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}

\rhead {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}

\cfoot{\fancyplain{\thepage}{}}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). For example, A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: `\section[Section title xxx]{Section title xxx\footnote{yyy}}`

Answer (score 1):

The optional argument to `\section` is used for the table of contents and the page headers. So you want

```
\section[Section title]{Section title\footnote{footnote text}}
```

If you also need a different page header, for instance if the title is very long, add also

```
\sectionmark{Short title}
```

just after the line shown before.